# How to use parametrized query to extract node property in py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a NEO4J database and i need to pass parametric query to retrieve properties of a node using Py2neo library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Let's take an example that you have a node property *Name* on which you need to extract the data.

In below example we took a key *'Node_Name'* and put a where clause on *Name* property. While executing the query we passed the condition value (xyz) in `parameters` clause matching to that key. You can use multiple key by comma-separation in the `parameters` clause.

```
query = "Match (n:P)-[:next]->(P) where n.Name={ Node_Name } return P.Name"
result = graph.cypher.execute(query, parameters={"Node_Name": "xyz"})
```

Let me know if this address your problem.

Comment: yes this was my problem,Thanks...